# TFS on Virtual Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, team-foundation-server, version-control, build-server, virtualization

Is a small Virtual Server with 2 cores (1.6GHz) and 1GB RAM capable of running a Team Foundation Server for Version Control and Building with ~5 Users?
Nothing else will run on the system (except of the OS itself).

I ask this, because on the Microsoft Website there are some higher spec requirements listed.
But they are for up to 250 Users.

The project is small and build time on our local systems is about 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. At least not for me. That machine likely also has slow IO and seriously you will be in a lot of trouble starting with not even a grpahics card worth of memory.

It likely will work, but it will seriouslyx be painfull and die a death by permanent swapping.

Comment: Couldn't really believe this answer and tested it. He is right.